# (PHP-GoDaddy) cURL API request to Atlassian/Jira domain fails/returns nothing

Tags: php, api, curl, jira, shared-hosting

We have a GoDaddy website that we use for our company workflow. Some of its features are integrated with our Atlassian/Jira domain via REST API using PHP cURL. Before a week ago, everything worked fine but then for the last week all our cURL methods fail ONLY WHEN connecting to our Atlassian/Jira domain VIA GoDaddy. The same methods work on localhost and on other hostings like 000webhosting.

I've tried:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 20
```

Also tried setting the Basic Auth as a header instead of CURLOPT_USERPWD.

CURLOPT_HEADER returns an array that only has a value for the "url" property, everything else is 0 or empty, even the http status. Result from curl_exec is also empty. curl_getinfo shows the same info as CURLOPT_HEADER, only containing the URL and everything else empty.

The cURL works for other URLs like Google.

We are on Deluxe Shared Hosting.

Our authentication format: Basic "username@atlassiandomain.com:API_TOKEN"

Example of curl info:

```
Array
(
    [url] => (das a secret)
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 2.215
    [namelookup_time] => 0.046
    [connect_time] => 0.046
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_ip] => xx.xxx.xxx.xx
    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
    [local_port] => xxxxx
    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

UPDATE: found this error with curl_error() ::
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, our php curl (5.3) didn't support TLS 1.2 in curl_setopt() -> CURLOPT_SSLVERSION